Vuetify tooltip text always visible on mobile after touch
I'm using vuetify tooltip on v-icon. The tooltip text is supposed to be visible on hover, which works as expected for desktop. On mobile (or any touch screen device), it should not at all be visible. It looks fine on mobile view of devTool but on actual mobile phone, when the icon is touched, the tooltip text is visible(which should not be the case), and is hidden only when somewhere else on the screen is touched.
<v-tooltip :text="textTooltip" location="top">
     <template #activator="{ props }">
         <v-icon
              icon="mdi-circle"
              v-bind="props"
         ></v-icon>
     </template>
 </v-tooltip>

According to vuetify documentation, open-on-click is false and open-on-hover is true by default.
https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-tooltip/

Why do you not want it to be visible on mobile? That's a great accessible UX done for you. You could always have a conditional and change the values of open-on-click/hover if you want to ship a subpar experience to your users.

@kissu Since the text is not automatically disappearing on mobile after touch, it forces the user for an extra touch to make it disappear. That's why I don't want its visibility. The other solution could be using close-delay, but it also delays closing on desktop hover, which I don't want.

@ShivamChaudhary have you tried using the disabled prop? It will still show the tooltip, but prevent the user from clicking on it

Just let the default web behavior tbh, less confusing for anyone or just remove the hover part entirely with something more static.
